# how can I create a middleware for URL authentication? I am using Laravel and PHP 7.1

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fixing a bug in a system. A blocked user can access pages that should be restricted for them if they know the URL to go the page. I'm using Laravel and PHP 7.1, I'm still new, but know how to create a basic middleware.

IN kernel,

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'       => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' =>\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can'        => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'throttle'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'guest'      => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'admin'      => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,

    ];
```

In controller, well i want to put something as parameter to block user only with id=3 (my code is totally wrong, i know)

```
    public function __construct(BlockRestricType::$ID)
    {
    if('ID'= 3)
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean php 7.1 and laravel 5.8? Put some effort to setup a middleware for your endpoints and if you have issues after trying we can help

Comment: There is great documentation on the Laravel website: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Comment: use  [signed urls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#signed-urls)

Answer (score 1):

The authentication middleware in laravel is auth
You can use for authenticated logged user to handle what you want!

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    // put the routes here 
Route::get('dashboard','HomeController@index');
});
```

or

```
Route::get('dashboard','HomeController@index')->middleware('auth')
```

Comment: Is it works for url too? If user click the back button on browser ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138882/why-my-middleware-is-not-working-i-try-to-put-some-parameter-inside-the-middlewa