# Why my middleware is not working,I try to put some parameter inside the middleware and its not working

Tags: laravel-5.7, php-7.1

My middleware should block user with restric_desc = Revoke Student Portal Access. But it end up blocking all user from accessing the tab.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'request' =>App\Models\BlockReason::where('IS_ACTIVE','0')->pluck('ID')], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'block', 'request' => App\Models\BlockRestricType::where('RESTRIC_DESC', 'Revoke Student Portal Access')->pluck('ID')],function(){
```

My middleware

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $var= $request->route()->getAction();

    if($request->IS_ACTIVE != 0){
        if($request->RESTRIC_DESC == 'Revoke Student Portal Access'){
        return redirect('/');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```